# AddEventListener doesn't see scope

Tags: javascript, event-handling, react-hooks, onclicklistener

When I set a handler using OnClick it works fine and console.log always use the actual state. But when I use AddEventListener it works only once and then use the old state.

What the reason for than behaviour??

see the link
https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-star-wf3c9?file=/src/App.js

P.S Using [count] as useEffect dependence fix it, but it just create new listener each time, don't think that the right way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a closure issue.

In fact in each render your component going to create a new function showCount that you fixed the count.

For exemple:

In 1st render you create a function showCount  that you fixed count = 1.

In your 2nd render you create a function showCount  that you fixed count = 2.

In your 3 render you create a function showCount  that you fixed count = 3.

The issue is that you are not changing the showcount when your count changes like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let buttonShow = document.querySelector(".buttonShow");
    buttonShow.addEventListener("click", showCount, true);
    return () => {
      buttonShow.removeEventListener("click", showCount, true);
    };
  }, [count]);
```

You can see the log count 2 because the reference of the count doesn't change when you use incremental.

I think the best solution is to you use a Component class:

```
import React from "react";

    class CounterAddEvent extends React.PureComponent {
      state = {
        count: 1
      };
      componentDidMount() {
        let buttonShow = document.querySelector(".buttonShow");
        buttonShow.addEventListener("click", this.showCount, true);
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
        let buttonShow = document.querySelector(".buttonShow");
        buttonShow.removeEventListener("click", this.showCount, true);
      }
      increaseCount = () => {
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
      };
      showCount = () => {
        console.log(this.state.count);
      };
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.increaseCount} className="input">
              increase
            </button>
            <button>{this.state.count}</button>
            <button className="buttonShow">Show console</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default CounterAddEvent;
```

Comment: thanx for the reply. I see the closure here, but why function showCount doesn't see the actual state of count. Here you can see, that closure can see the actual value. Why it doesn't work in my case?
https://jsfiddle.net/a8u6dfc3/

Comment: Because the reference does'nt change. It is that reason in your issue you can see the log  of count 2

Comment: I think I almost see what you saying. In this case each render we have NOT the same count, BUT the new one?? Because than the only explanation I see, why it doesn't see the changes

Answer (score 0):

Bug came from setting "useState(1)" this will always reinitialize the value "count" to 1 before implementing "++count";

So the simple trick that i used was to refactor the useState(1) to  useState(x) ..
so to that x can be updated from the current count value..

Below is the Refactored Code...

[image]

Comment: thank you for your way of solving it. It probably break the pure functions rule. Anyway, that was really interesting to see! great!

Comment: and by the way, that works NOT because you reinitialize State, you just take count from outside variable. In fact, "The initial value will be assigned only on the initial render" according to the documentation. This code works the same way:
https://prnt.sc/tigzm9